# Is a TEXT.IX file familiar to anyone?

Tags: database

Just curious which legacy DOS based system is responsible for a 'TEXT.IX' data file.

If anyone has come across it before please tell :-)  Thanks.

Comment: If it's really from the DOS days, it could be anything -- there was no enforced association between file extensions and applications, and the "dot three" part of "eight dot three" was, as often as not, used to categorize things like WordPerfect documents within a directory. Framemaker indexes are the canonical owner, but don't rely on that actually being the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Possibly Framemaker](http://filext.com/file-extension/IX) (Adobe Systems).

Answer (score 1):

http://filext.com/file-extension/ix